# How to change price line woocommerce (subscriptions)?

Tags: woocommerce, price, woocommerce-subscriptions

For my webshop I am using Woocommerce together with Woocommerce Subscriptions to sell subscriptions. The Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin generates a string here that is added to the price which looks like:

"$0.00 / month for 3 months and a $20.00 sign-up fee"

Which is a really weird way of saying "$20" which I want it to say.

With the use of certain plug ins it is possible to change the first part ($0.00), the price itself but it is not possible to change the rest or remove this (presumably because this is done in Subscriptions and not in Woocommerce itself).

The reason the product is a subscription is because it's a product I will be shipping out for multiple (e.g) 3 Months that is payed in advance. So I want it to be part of subscriptions to be consistent.

So I want to change the pricing string so that it shows up as simply "$20" in the cart, subtotal and corresponding email.

Thank you, Help!

Comment: I am trying to achieve this exact same thing. I am curious what plugin you use to change the first part ($0.00) I have a solution for the second part below.

Answer (score 2):

There are two hooks readily available in Woo that can change the html wording and can also help for translation if I am not mistaken, as well. The two are:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', '49177935_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', '49177935_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

You can add a function to your child-theme functions to test this:

```
function 491777935_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) { 

    $products_with_price_str = array( ...$id(s) or logic... );
    if ( in_array( $product->id, $products_with_price_str ) ) { 

        $pricestring = str_replace( 'every 3 months', wc_clean($0.00)'', $pricestring );
        $pricestring = str_replace( 'sign on fee', 'wc_clean($20.00)', $pricestring);
    }
    return $pricestring;
}
```

I believe this should help you and I always find that it is useful to look at the core functions and methods directly in the core of Woocommerce. This could be more confusing for some as you will not want to use most, of any, core statements in *your* functions, but it does help visualize how they do it.